# try avoid null reference with SingleOrDefault

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

I have this query which is join from 2 entities

```
.GroupJoin(uow.Airports.List(),fbm=>fbm.FlyBillMains.AirPortId_Arrival,arr=>arr.AirPortId,(fbm,arr)=>new FlyBillMainDetails
                   {
                       BranchName = fbm.BranchName,
                       CompanyCode = fbm.CompanyCode,
                       CompanyName = fbm.CompanyName,
                       CustomerName = fbm.CustomerName,
                       FlyBillMains = fbm.FlyBillMains,
                       PayTypeName = fbm.PayTypeName,
                       PolicyCode = fbm.PolicyCode,
                       CountryName = fbm.CountryName,
                       AirportNameArrival=arr.SingleOrDefault().Name,
                       Address = fbm.Address,
                       ShipperName = fbm.ShipperName,
                       ShipperAddress = fbm.ShipperAddress,
                       ShipperPhone = fbm.ShipperPhone,
                       ConsigeeName = fbm.ConsigeeName,
                       ConsigeeAddress = fbm.ConsigeeAddress,
                       ConsigeePhone = fbm.ConsigeePhone
                   })
```

in this line

```
AirportNameArrival=arr.SingleOrDefault().Name
```

i got the null reference if AirportNameArrival is null 
Knowing that  AirportNameArrival  is string

Comment: no i'm confused work fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Null-conditional Operator `?.`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx):

```
string AirportNameArrival = arr.SingleOrDefault()?.Name;
```

You also can combine it with [Null-coalescing operator `??`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) to get empty string by default:

```
string AirportNameArrival = arr.SingleOrDefault()?.Name??"";
```

Comment: yes null reference fixed but the null values not appear in the list

Comment: @haithamsha Would you prefer `""` instead of `null`? Would `??` help?